# Did the Q React to V'ger's Evolution?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-q

In Star Trek: The Motion Picture, we see that:

> V'ger is actually the Voyager 6 probe sent by NASA back in the 20th century. Decker "merges" with V'ger and together they become humanity's next "step" in evolution.

Do we know if/how the Q Continuum reacted to this? Is there any record as to how they reacted?

As Picard once theorizes (in TNG) to Q, he believes they were actually *afraid* of humanity. That at some point, humanity would "evolve even beyond the capacities of the Q". Q does not seem to take kindly to this "blasphemy". What Decker did would certainly qualify potentially as this evolutionary step. Yes?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Q (and the other Q) have never referred to V'ger in canon and not in any EU novel.

Comment: I think the "humanity passing the Q" angle was just a result of early-TNG writing. In-universe, based on how the Q are pretty close to omnipotence and that they're also not exactly known for being trustworthy, I think it's far more likely that Q was trying to butter up Picard and Riker just to play games with them. In later seasons (when the writing is better), there's no more talk of humanity one day passing the Q.